# If $y_1''(x)-y_1(x)=\cos(x)^2$, $y_2''(x)-y_2(x)=-\sin(x)^2$, $y_1(0)=y'_1(0)=1=y_2(0)=y'_2(0)=1$, then $y_1(1)>y_2(1)$ or $y_1(1)<y_2(1)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I got the following question from a test:

$$y_1''-y_1=\cos(x)^2, y_1(0)=1, y'_1(0)=1$$
$$y_2''-y_2=-\sin(x)^2, y_2(0)=1, y'_2(0)=1$$
Does $y_1(1)>y_2(1)$ or $y_1(1)<y_2(1)$?
It is quite easy to solve those equations, but I'm looking for other option to solve this, because I'm sure they aimed to another way of solution.

Comment: @Moo
Second order equation- homogeneous solution and private solution for non-homogeneous.
for the non-homogeneous, notice that $cos(2x)=cos(x)^2-sin(x)^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe they wanted you to subtract both equations and define $w=y_2-y_1$.

$$y''_2-y''_1-(y_2-y_1)=-1\implies w''-w=-1$$

Solving the resulting equation is trivial as one can directly write down the solution

$$w=c_1\exp(t)+c_2\exp(-t)+1.$$

Note, that $w(0)=y_2(0)-y_1(0)=0$ and $w'(0)=y_2'(0)-y_1'(0)=0$.